# Stripe Webhooks: Invoice.paid vs Checkout.Session.Completed

Tags: django, stripe-payments, webhooks

I use Stripes' webhooks and want to get notified, if the customer successfully "paid the bill". I came across two webhooks, which in my opinion both could do the job:

1. Webhook "invoice.paid" - According to Stripe doc: Occurs whenever an invoice payment attempt succeeds or an invoice is marked as paid out-of-band.
2. Webhook "checkout.session.completed" - According to Stripe doc: Occurs when a Checkout Session has been successfully completed.

**My questions are:**

1. I don't understand the second part of the "invoice.paid" webhook: "invoice is marked as paid out-of-band" -> What does "out-of-band" mean? Is this to be considered a successful payment?
2. Regarding "checkout.session.complete" -> This can also occur, if payment fails - correct?
3. Which webhooks shall I consider (or are there other webhooks) to see the status "customer paid the bill successfully"?
4. What is more, I don't really know if disputes should be considered as successful payments or not: On one hand, I get a invoice.paid webhook, on the other hand, I get a charge.dispute.created webhook. geeezus...

I appreciate your help! Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I don't understand the second part of the "invoice.paid" webhook: "invoice is marked as paid out-of-band" -> What does "out-of-band" mean? Is this to be considered a successful payment?

This is specifically referring to marking an invoice [paid out of band](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/pay#pay_invoice-paid_out_of_band) (ie, the customer paid you outside of Stripe and you want to mark the Stripe invoice paid **without collecting a payment**). This will not involve an actual payment, but does transition the invoice to `status=paid` so this event fires.

> Regarding "checkout.session.complete" -> This can also occur, if payment fails - correct?

This event signals only that the Checkout session is complete. Depending on the [`mode`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-mode) use for Checkout, this may or may not involve a payment. If an immediate payment is expected, the session will only complete if that payment is successful. For example `mode=setup` or `mode=subscription` with a free trial will not involve an immediate payment. A subscription with trial, though, will create a $0 invoice and fire `invoice.paid`.

> Which webhooks shall I consider (or are there other webhooks) to see
> the status "customer paid the bill successfully"?

This depends on what you mean by "paid" and "bill". If you mean specifically for invoices (whether related to subscriptions or not), then `invoice.paid` is a good choice. You can then filter for amounts greater than $0 etc to further constrain was "paid" means.

> What is more, I don't really know if disputes should be considered as
> successful payments or not: On one hand, I get a invoice.paid webhook,
> on the other hand, I get a charge.dispute.created webhook.

Disputes are not payments, and should be an entirely separate discussion. You can only have a dispute after a payment. Suggest starting by reading the [docs on disputes](https://stripe.com/docs/disputes).

**To summarize**: What are you really trying to do? These events are related and sometimes overlap, but not always. It highly depends on what you're doing.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much! 1) 2) 3) Webhooks: Customers are subscribing (mode='subscription' and without any trail) and getting credits (via webhooks) in return. The goal is to top up their credits only if the invoice is paid successfully. As far as I understood, both webhooks would be possible in this case. However, in my opinion, the webhook "invoice.paid" seems to be the better fit, since it targets the actual "completed payment/transaction" better. Agree? 4) Fantastic - thanks for the docs.

Comment: In that case I'd agree that's probably simpler, as it would also cover your renewals each month/year/whatever period, instead of splitting logic for first/recurring invoices. Just be aware that this even will also fire if you ever start using one-off invoices, so you may want to additionally inspect the `subscription` property in future. https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object#invoice_object-subscription

Answer (score 2):

#### What's going on?

- When you create a checkout session it will have an id, which you'll store in your database next to the user who started the checkout session.
- When you receive an invoice.paid webhook event, it **does not** have any link back to the checkout session! (so you'll know *someone* paid, but you won't know *who* paid!)
- checkout.session.completed solves this because it contains the id of the checkout session *and* the stripe customer id, which allows you to link the two, so you basically have a mapping from *your* customer ids to *stripe's* customer ids.
- So simply grab the customer id from the checkout.session.completed event and store it in your database next to the relevant user, that way you'll be able to tell which one of your users is paying you when you receive an invoice.paid event!

#### How can this be implemented?

1. When a checkout session is started, store the checkout session id next to the user who started the session so you can look it up later
2. When you see `checkout.session.completed`, look at the accompanying JSON and take the stripe customer number and store it in your database (e.g. a column like stripe_id in users table). To figure out which of your users it's for, use the checkout session id to look it up in your database (i.e. the data you stored in step 1)
3. Now that you have the stripe customer id stored in your users table, whenever you see `invoice.paid`, look at the accompanying JSON, take the stripe customer number, look it up in your users table to find who paid, and update the expiry date of their subscription to 1 month into the future.

That's it!

#### Also good to know

- *Both* `checkout.session.completed` and `invoice.paid` events are triggered when someone new subscribes, and *only* `invoice.paid` is triggered each month thereafter (presuming the user had enough funds and didn't cancel)
- You can get to the stripe customer number in both webhook events like so (this is ruby, but should be similar with js or python):

```rb
payload = request.body.read
data = JSON.parse(payload, symbolize_names: true)
data.object.customer
=> "cus_Lvyv721cJGpYB1"
```

Comment: How do you make sure `checkout.session.completed` gets called before `invoice.paid`?

Comment: @MondoDuke I'm guessing here (so I'm interested to hear what others say), but I think if your app receives `invoice.paid` and can't find which customer paid (i.e. your app hasn't received `checkout.session.completed` for that customer yet), then your app should **not** return a 200. Because Stripe doesn't receive the 200, it knows to periodically retry both events. Once your app has processed `checkout.session.completed`, then `invoice.paid` will work and the process will compete successfully. But I'm guessing, it would be good to confirm via an official source (docs or someone from stripe).

Comment: @MondoDuke one other thing (from [here](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/best-practices#retry-logic)): *Stripe attempts to deliver your webhooks for up to three days with an exponential back off.*

Comment: I see, thanks. Another way I can think is to create a stripe customer whenever you create a checkout link for a user, so that you have their customerid and userid stored in advance. Not sure which method to use, their docs are kind of bad.

Comment: @MondoDuke the two critical mechanics are: 1. when you create a checkout session, make sure you record the id, so that when you later receive a webhook with that id, you'll be able to associate it back to your customer (otherwise you'll know someone completed checkout but you won't be able to find out who). And 2. That webhook will also give you a stripe customer number. Store it beside your user, and that way every time in the future that you get an `invoice.paid` you can observe its stripe customer number and look that number up in your users table to figure out who just paid you.

Comment: I think your first step isn't needed - you can store your backend's USERID in the checkout.metadata

Comment: @MondoDuke interesting, I can't think of any reason that wouldn't work. I think so long as you have *some* way to identify which of your app's users completed checkout, then that would work.

Comment: @MondoDuke not to sway you either way (because it might not be necessary), but one thing I like about my approach is by storing more info about the checkout session it might make debugging edgecases easier in the future. I might just be too thorough or too risk averse but the idea of having all info in my db in case something unexpected happens is appealing to me (although possibly unnecessary)

Comment: True, that's probably better

Comment: Incredibly helpful, thanks you so much for this in depth answer!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone runs into this problem when testing, make sure that you are testing a puchase on a subscription. If it is a one time payment, checkout.session.complete "customer" : CUSTOMER_ID will be null.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).