# Stripe manage subscription - invoice.paid and checkout.session.completed

Tags: stripe-payments

I've seen [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64809805/stripe-webhooks-invoice-paid-vs-checkout-session-completed), but it did not answer the question asked.

I can't understand how to manage re-occurring subscription.

I did a test and the following events were fired after a successful `Stripe Checkout` test payment:

- `charge.succeeded`
- `checkout.session.completed`
- `payment_method.attached`
- `invoice.created`
- `customer.subscription.created`
- `invoice.updated`
- `customer.subscription.updated`
- `invoice.finalized`
- `invoice.paid`

My issue is that both `checkout.session.completed` and `invoice.paid` is getting fired. I understand that session can be completed in the following cases

- failure
- cancel
- start of a trial
- successful start

`Stripe` docs says [this](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/checkout#provision-and-monitor):

> The minimum event types to monitor:
>
> | `EVENT NAME` | `DESCRIPTION` |
> | --- | --- |
> | `checkout.session.completed` | Sent when a customer clicks the Pay or Subscribe button in Checkout, informing you of a new purchase. |
> | `invoice.paid` | Sent each billing interval when a payment succeeds. |
> | `invoice.payment_failed` | Sent each billing interval if there is an issue with your customer’s payment method. |

And in the code part:

> For `checkout.session.completed`:
>
> # You should provision the subscription and save the customer ID to your database.
>
> For `invoice.paid`:
>
> # Continue to provision the subscription as payments continue to be made.

So then I thought there was surely a way to identify that `checkout.session.completed` and `invoice.paid` would be related to each other, but then the problem is that `checkout.session.completed` does not contain any `Invoice` id and the `invoice.paid` does not contain an id for the `CheckoutSession` where it was created from.

How do I give users only one month of subscription, instead of 2? Does `Stripe` even keep track of the end of the subscription?

Because in the [`tracking` section here](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/webhooks#tracking), it says:

> 1. ...
> 2. Your site receives an invoice.paid event.
> 3. Your webhook endpoint finds the customer for whom payment was just made.
> 4. Your webhook endpoint updates the customer’s current_period_end timestamp in your database to the appropriate date in the future (plus a day or two for leeway).

So this page ignore the `checkout.session.completed` endpoint entirely and relies on `invoice.paid` only, which supposedly may only arrive hours later than the session completed. (I can't find the link on this.)

Answer (score 0):

> My issue is that both `checkout.session.completed` and `invoice.paid` is getting fired. I understand that session can be completed in the following cases
>
> - failure
> - cancel
> - start of a trial
> - successful start

This is not correct.  `checkout.session.completed` only fires when the Checkout Session completes successfully.  [The documentation in the API reference for `checkout.session.completed`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-checkout.session.completed) event says:

> Occurs when a Checkout Session has been successfully completed.

I noticed you mentioned this quote from the documentation regarding this event:

> Sent when a customer clicks the Pay or Subscribe button in Checkout, informing you of a new purchase.

The keywords there are "informing you of a new purchase"; this event will not fire on failure to pay (i.e. when no purchase has been made).  It will be fired on successful creation of a Subscription with a trial though.

> So then I thought there was surely a way to identify that `checkout.session.completed` and `invoice.paid` would be related to each other, but then the problem is that `checkout.session.completed` does not contain any `Invoice` id and the `invoice.paid` does not contain an id for the `CheckoutSession` where it was created from.

The Checkout Session will specify the associated Subscription in [its `subscription` property](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-subscription).  From there you can look at that [Subscription's `latest_invoice` property](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object#subscription_object-latest_invoice) to get the latest Invoice ID.

---

To determine if you should provide whatever goods or services your customer is subscribing to you may want to use [the `customer.subscription.updated` event](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-customer.subscription.updated).  This will give you updates about changes to [the `status` of the Subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object#subscription_object-status), and you can provision based on that `status`.  For example, if the `status` is `trialing` or `active` give them access, but if it's anything else don't give them access.

Comment: This sounds like I only need `customer.subscripton.updated` because it handles renewal, trial -> active, cancellation. A more customer-friendly solution might include `invoice.payment_failed` for notifying them ahead of time, but overall `customer.subscription.updated` handles all cases based on that. But then I don't understand why the documentation says 'minimum event types to monitor' or what it means. Can I just return `400` status code in the webhook for `checkout.session.completed`, `invoice.paid` and `invoice.payment_failed`?

Comment: `invoice.paid` and `invoice.payment_failed` are recommended instead of `customer.subscription.updated` in the docs you linked to in your original question because the former events are more specific and easier to process.  `customer.subscription.updated` fires a lot more often and for a lot more reasons, so you need to write more code to inspect what changed and determine what actions to take, if any.